# list_display not showing email_verified field in ModelAdmin Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-admin-actions

I am list displaying the following fields in Django ModelAdmin.

```
list_display = ['username', 'email_verified', 'cert_password', 'key_name']
```

in this list the items - `username, cert_password and key_name` belongs to a a model `ModelName` and the item `email_verified` belongs to other model `ModelName2`.

But I want to display them all to admin in `ModelAdmin` so for that I created a function def `email_verified` as below:

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['username', 'email_verified', 'cert_password', 'key_name']
    def email_verified(self):
        return ModelName2.email_verified
    actions = [my_action_here]
```

So, when I returned `ModelName2.email_verified` its showing `<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x7efcca3b9910>` in the Admin interface through ModelAdmin.

So, I tried through the following:

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['username', 'email_verified', 'cert_password', 'key_name']
    def email_verified(self,obj):
        return ModalName2.objects.get().email_verified
    actions = [my_action_here]
```

But in this case I got the error - `get() returned more than one ModalName2`
So, how can I do it.

I want to display the value of `email_verified` in the ModalAdmin (Admin Interface) in the table with the respective username and other fields.

eg. What I want -

```
Username | Email_Verified | cert_password | Key_name
abcuser  | 1              | asdf          | asdf
bhdjs    | 1              | lkj           | ljk
asdff    | 0              | lkjsd         | ljl
```

Here are my modals -

```
class ModelName2(models.Model):
    username = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email_verified = models.BooleanField(
        default=False,
        help_text="Valid - <b><a>True</a></b> OR <b><a>False</a></b>")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.username)

class ModelName1(models.Model):

    username = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cert_password = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        default='',
        blank=True,
        help_text="<b><a>System Generated - Do not alter</a></b>")
    key_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=15,
        default='',
        blank=True,
        help_text="<b><a>System Generated - Do not alter</a></b>")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.username)
```

How to do it? I am using Django 1.11.X

Comment: Do `ModelName` and `ModelName2` linked with each other? Can you post models also to make your probem more clear?

Comment: `ModalName2.objects.get()` where the filter for get()

Comment: Models added @neverwalkaloner

Comment: `return ModalName2.objects.get(username=obj.username).email_verified`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ModalName2.objects.get()` should return only one object. Otherwise it raise the error. 
As for your problem you don't need `ModalName2.objects.get()` queryset actually. Since `obj` argument is `ModelName` instance you can just do following:

```
def email_verified(self,obj):
    return obj.username.modelname2.email_verified
```

Note you can access `OneToOneField` backwards using lowercased model name `modelname2`.

Also since `username` attribute returning `User` instance, it would be better to rename it to `user`:

```
class ModelName1(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Also I recommend you to join `ModelName` and `ModelName1` as one model and use single `OneToOneField` instead of two.